# why this css selector is not working with fontawsome

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, font-awesome

When i try to apply jquery event or css style on element  it does not work, instead if use a static one like id="delCoord" and change the css/jquery even listener, it works. Can someone explain why

note i use fontawsome free 5.6.3.
Thanks

```js
$('body').on('click', 'span[id^="edit-delCoordSet"]', function() {
  alert('YOU SHOULD SEE ME !!!!!');
  return false; // i just set this up for tests !!!
  var coordsValueIdx = $(this).parent('.editCoords').attr('data-elNumber');
  console.log('try to delete: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
  jqEl = $(this);
  console.log('html element ' + jqEl);
  updateCaveCoords(coordsValueIdx, '', '', jqEl, add = false, del = true, modify = false)
});
```

```css
span[id^="edit-delCoordSet"] {
  padding: 0.3em 1em 0.3em 1em;
}

span[id^="edit-delCoordSet"]:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="editCoords" data-elnumber="0">
  X:<input type="text" class="coords" data-elnumber="0" value="4.8552"> Y:
  <input type="text" class="coords" data-elnumber="1" value="43.32000"> Z:
  <input type="text" class="coords" data-elnumber="2" value="475"> &nbsp;
  <span class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" id="edit-delCoordSet-0"></span>
</div>

<div class="editCoords" data-elnumber="1">
  X:<input type="text" class="coords" data-elnumber="0" value="4.8552"> Y:
  <input type="text" class="coords" data-elnumber="1" value="43.32000"> Z:
  <input type="text" class="coords" data-elnumber="2" value="475"> &nbsp;
  <span class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" id="edit-delCoordSet-1"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/cvbsaxnt/1/ Are they any errors in your console?

Comment: No, no error on console.

Comment: I edited your question and used SO's snippet-handler. With that snippet, I cannot reproduce the behaviour you described. Can you?  Actually, one think that might help you is if you turned that one `span` into a `div`(which gets the id) and a `span`which has just the fa-attributes.

Comment: Ok I found the culprit !
I was using fontawsome jquery extensions. So my <span> was replace by <svg> tags (with the same id and settings of course).

I change fontawsome loading with this options : 
data-auto-replace-svg="nest"

More info there https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the culprit !
I was using fontawsome jquery extensions. So my  was replace by  tags (with the same id and settings of course).

I change fontawsome loading with this options : 
data-auto-replace-svg="nest"

More info there https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery